# How to make Heroku load faster

Tags: reactjs, heroku, dyno

I have deployed a portolio app to heroku but it loads slowly on heroku versus locally it loads fast. I have tried to add a monitor bot (https://uptimerobot.com/) to reload the app every 30 minutes. However I eventually run out of hours of free dyno. Are there any other solutions? Or any other place I can deploy my app to.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku isn't loading slowly, it puts your app to sleep when it hasn't been in use for 30 minutes to save up dyno hours. It only takes a minute to boot the first time because you are waking it back up. Just like a computer takes a minute to wake up, it isn't because it's slow, it's because it was asleep.
[Heroku dyno sleeping documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours#dyno-sleeping)

Comment: thanks im a new reputation user here I appreciate this chris

Comment: If the answer helped you or you think it answers your question tap the checkmark on the answer. 